# accdb to mysql on mac (os_11.6/Big_Sur)

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc, workbench

I did create an access database for my college assignment and later on I switched my pc to mac. Since then, I've been trying to import the accdb file to mysql workbench but nothing seems to be working.

any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: First export data from access to excel then import that excel to MySQL database. MAC doesn't support access.

Comment: That make sense. However, I wanted to import entire database to mysql workbench at once. I managed to create a dump file through a software. When I try to import the dump file it throws an error

Comment: 00:32:08 Restoring /Users/munnarahman/Desktop/dump/dump.sql Running: /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/mysql --defaults-file="/var/folders/hz/l4gwyvwj1d545rh3c7kd8__80000gp/T/tmp2qqi5zlc/extraparams.cnf"  --protocol=tcp --host=127.0.0.1 --user=root --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments --database=studentenrolmentdb  < "/Users/munnarahman/Desktop/dump/dump.sql" ERROR 1069 (42000) at line 41: Too many keys specified; max 1 keys allowed  Operation failed with exitcode 1 00:32:08 Import of /Users/munnarahman/Desktop/dump/dump.sql has finished with 1 errors

Comment: @Harun24HR thanks for the kind info. I have managed to transfer few tables to mysql but few tables giving errors. for example- Unhandled exception: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 165: ordinal not in range(128)

Check the log for more details.